# raspberry pi hangs after 2-3 days of continous use

Tags: raspbian, python, pygame

I am using latest the Raspbian Wheezy release with kernel 3.10. I am running four Python programs 24 hours/day on the Raspberry Pi. Three programs out of four are like background services, which consume at the maximum 2.4% CPU and around 1.2% memory each. The fourth Python code is a pygame application that is displayed on a 1920x1080 screen, which consumes about 50% CPU and 2.4% memory. Thus in total when I am running all 4 programs total memory used is 90 MB and 60% CPU is in use all the time.

The problem is that Raspberry Pi suddenly hangs (no response the keyboard nor mouse, and I'm also not able to ping) after 2-3 days and thus we have to reboot it forcefully. What could be the reason for it to hang? There is no problem of a memory leak since even after 2-3 days the total memory usage and CPU usage is unchanged.

Comment: Possibly check your temps. I don't expect it but there could be a chance at those resolutions the temperature causes a crash. Strange it happens after such a long period, usually is memory leaks but as you say monitoring didn't point to that being the issue either.

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs"?  Have you checked the system logs?

Comment: By "hangs" I mean the raspberry doesn't respond to anything like keyboard, mouse and also I am not able to ping raspberry pi. Only devices which are connected to raspberry are ethernet cable, keyboard, mouse and HDTV using hdmi cable.

Comment: I checked system logs but it didn't show anything.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by "hang"? I had problems with my headless pi that every 2-3 days I could not connect to it. It was working ok but I could not ping nor ssh to it.
Turned out to be a problem with the power management in the wifi dongle:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=51543&p=397663

Once I turned of the power management features as described in the link it worked continuously again

Comment: People ought not to buy anything wifi based in realtek chips. My pi also hanged until I switched the realtek one to a ralink.

Answer (score 0):

If you overclocked, double check that and maybe set a lower frequency. One does not simply set "Turbo" or "Pi2" as an overclock in `raspi-config`. I've experienced this with extreme stress testing and a serious overclock. Clocking down solved my issue.